# Custom combobox selected text within wpf application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a wpf application , in which I have this problem :

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="VSP">
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel 
                        VirtualizingPanel.CacheLength="20"
                        VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Item"
                        VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
                        VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="ExpertTemplate">
                    <Grid Width="640">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="160"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="160"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="160" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="160"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Content="{Binding fsign_id}" Grid.Column="0"   />
                        <Label Content="{Binding fsign_civilite}" Grid.Column="1" />
                        <Label Content="{Binding fsign_nom}" Grid.Column="2"  />
                        <Label Content="{Binding fsign_prenom}" Grid.Column="3"  />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </UserControl.Resources>
        .............
         <DataGrid x:Name="grid"  ItemsSource="{Binding Entitites}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue}"   >
                <DataGrid.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                </Style>
                 </DataGrid.Resources>
                 <DataGrid.Columns>
                                  <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Participant" Width="200">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <skin:ParticipantExpert  SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedElement, Mode=TwoWay,  UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"  ItemsPanel="{StaticResource VSP}"  ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ExpertTemplate }"   Width="220"      ItemsSource="{Binding ExpertCollection}"  >

                                            </skin:ParticipantExpert>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                  </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

the customized combobox :

```
 public class ParticipantExpert : ComboBox 
    {

        public ParticipantExpert()
        {

        } 
        protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (SelectedItem == null) { return; }
            vue_groupe_participant CurrentItem = (vue_groupe_participant)SelectedItem;
            Text = CurrentItem.fsign_nom + "   " + CurrentItem.fsign_prenom;
        }

    }
```

I put a breakpoint in this line `if (SelectedItem == null) { return; }` . When I select an element from the combobox the event is raised twice !! The first one `SelectedItem` is the selected object but in the second one it takes null as value.

So I need to know :

1. Why the event is raised two times?
2. How can I fix my code ?

Thanks,

Comment: Is it because of the `Text = ...` line? When you set a ComboBox's Text property it has the effect of changing the selection.

Comment: Can you describe, why do you need custom `ComboBox`? It looks like you just need to change some styles or templates.

Comment: @AndrewStephens how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrew Stephens is correct. You have to remove assignment of text from the handler. That text you are trying to show must be a property of the object bound as SelectedItem.

You need to read more for the [ComboBox.Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here is the important part

> Setting the Text property to a value that is not in the collection leaves the SelectedIndex unchanged.

That means you have to add a property to your bound object that gives the control the text you want to display. You are not allowed to create a Text property that is not originally part of the bound object.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with the `ItemTemplate`

My `ComboBox` looks like this:

```
<ComboBox Margin="12,6,12,0" SelectedIndex="{Binding DatabaseIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Databases}" 
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DatabaseComboTemplate}"/>
```

`ItemTemplate` looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DatabaseComboTemplate" DataType="ItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="20">
            <Image Source="/AppWPF;component/Images/DatabaseImage.ico" Height="16" Width="16"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding DatabaseDisplayString}" Margin="0,-3,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Output looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Plz Re-read my code I used `ItemTemplate` . I need to customize the text displayed in the combobox after selection (when the pop-up is closed)